# Excel Interop - Draw All Borders in a Range

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I see from Microsoft's documentation that I can access the particular border edges of a cell using the 'xlBordersIndex' property and for example set the border style for the left edge of a cell:

```
range.Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle =     Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
```

But what if I just want to draw all borders?  I have tried

```
range.BorderAround2();
```

but that just draws a box around the range itself, which I understand.  So then I tried

```
range.Cells.BorderAround2();
```

thinking that it would go through each of the cells within the range and place all borders around each cell.  This is not what occurred.  So in order to get all borders around all cells in a range, must I manually access each of the four border indices?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
private void AllBorders(Excel.Borders _borders)
    {
        _borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        _borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        _borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        _borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        _borders.Color = Color.Black;
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

Finally, I got it. I did this without impacting the performance too. I am taking a simple excel to explain here : 

**Before**

[image]

I managed to store the range as `A1:C4` in a variable dynamically in **exRange** and used the below code to give border

```
((Range)excelSheet.get_Range(exRange)).Cells.Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
```

**After**

[image]

Comment: +1! Setting directly the `lineStyle` property in `Borders` is not only simplier but also significantly faster than on each of the borders: in my case (sheets with ~50k cells), the operation went from ~145ms to ~35ms per sheet, which is a nice x4 improvement!.

Answer (score 9):

```
oRange = SHEET2.get_Range("a1", "a10");
oRange.Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
oRange.Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
oRange.Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
oRange.Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
```

Comment: Simplified: oRange.Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;

Comment: @LucaZiegler a plus for  .get_Item(..   that's the efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not yet familiar wit C#, but in VBA there are `Range.Borders(xlInsideVertical)` and `Range.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)` properties. Try to use macro-recorder and apply all borders for any workbook region. Perhaps that will help.

Comment: That's a good idea, using a macro to see how the native program handles it.  I ended up writing a function to draw all borders:

Answer (score 3):

Why not to do simply:

```
Excel.Range tRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
tRange.Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
tRange.Borders.Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin;
```

*Note: apply border after the row and cell (range) filled with data to get range simply using function **.UsedRange()***

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each range In ranges
    For Each row As Range In .Range(range).Rows
        row.Cells.BorderAround(XlLineStyle.xlContinuous)
        row.Cells.Borders.Item(XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        row.Cells.Borders.Item(XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range tRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
        tRange.Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        tRange.Borders.Weight = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Excel.Range tRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
tRange.Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
tRange.Borders.Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin;
```

That way is not working, you will get something like this:

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32586603)