# Add all borders on cells including center borders in excel using C# excel interop

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I tried making an excel file with borders on its cells. I tried the following code:

```
xlWorksheet.Range[xlWorksheet.Cells[13, 1], xlWorksheet.Cells[13,14]]
    .BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous,
    Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium);
```

but it is giving me the following output:

[image]

How will I add all borders of cells within specified range including the middle borders?

Comment: Michell ^^ http://stackoverflow.com/a/14760694/4273446